# SQL-Query - Join multiple tables with additional dynamic column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help for building a SQL-statement. The **Database-Schema** looks like this:

[image: SQL-Schema]

I did prepare the following **SQL-Fiddle**, which contains sample-data:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/831bab/1

As for the sample-data in the SQL-Fiddle, I want to query for the computername "Client02" and want to get the following result:

**Wanted result 1**

```
PrinterName   | PrintServer | PrinterActive | ComputerActive | isDefaultPrinter
PRT01_Zentral | DC01        | True          | True           | False
PRT02_BH      | DC01        | True          | True           | True
```

As for the sample-data in the SQL-Fiddle, I want to query for the computername "Client01" and want to get the following result:

**Wanted result 2**

```
PrinterName   | PrintServer | PrinterActive | ComputerActive | isDefaultPrinter
PRT01_Zentral | DC01        | True          | True           | True
```

As you see, I need to join all the tables and add something like a helper-column, which contains information about the default-printer. (True/False)

I started to build up the query, but I don't know how to proceed ...

```
SELECT printers.PrinterName, printers.PrintServer, printers.PrinterActive
FROM computermapping
LEFT JOIN computers ON computermapping.ComputerID = computers.ComputerID
LEFT JOIN printers ON computermapping.PrinterID = printers.PrinterID
LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter ON computers.ComputerID = computerdefaultprinter.ComputerID
WHERE computers.ComputerName = "Client02"
```

I think my request contains all the information, which is needed. The SQL-Fiddle has sample-data to easily reproduce it. The WantedResults should show the target clearly.

**EDIT:**
DBMS: MySQL

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Move the `computers.ComputerName = "Client02" ` condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: How do you recognize the default/non-default printer?

Comment: @RadimBača: Thank you for your inquiry. A computer can only have one default printer. The table ComputerDefaultPrinter contains the unique column ComputerID. IF a computerid is present for printerid => default printer.

Comment: Right, now I see it

Comment: and isn't the default printer for the computer 2 the `PRT02_BH`?

Comment: @RadimBača omg - I did just update the request ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following query to get the result that you need

```
SELECT printers.PrinterName, 
       printers.PrintServer, 
       printers.PrinterActive, 
       computers.ComputerActive, 
       CASE 
         WHEN computerdefaultprinter.PrinterID IS NULL THEN "false" 
         ELSE "true" 
       END AS isDefaultPrinter 
FROM   computermapping 
       LEFT JOIN computers 
              ON computermapping.ComputerID = computers.ComputerID 
       LEFT JOIN printers 
              ON computermapping.PrinterID = printers.PrinterID 
       LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter 
              ON computers.ComputerID = computerdefaultprinter.ComputerID 
                 AND printers.PrinterID = computerdefaultprinter.PrinterID 
WHERE  computers.ComputerName = "Client02"
```

I've only added *CASE...WHEN* statement and modified join condition of your original query.
But I think instead of using table *`computerdefaultprinter`*, why don't you add column *`IsDefaultPrinter`* to table *`computermapping`*.

```
CREATE TABLE `computermapping` (
  `ComputerMappingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PrinterID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ComputerID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IsDefaultPrinter` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that is, what I was looking for. I will test it , but I think it is OK. phpMyAdmin is telling me "Unknown keyword at AS", but it is working.

Comment: I didn't just add the column "isDefaultPrinter" to table "computermapping", because I thought about getting problems with the case, that a computer can only have one default printer.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add a if statement in your query, comparing the inner result (that can only be 1) to your outter select. There is a better way of achieving this probably but this answer reflects the queryresult's that you've asked.

Edit: I'm assuming only a default printer per computer.
Are you sure the wanted result 2 is correct? Because in the database, records are saying computer1 has 1 printerid (1) that is the default and that computer2 has 2 printers (1 and 2) and 2 is default.

```
SELECT printers.PrinterName,
       printers.PrintServer,
       printers.PrinterActive,
       IF (
             (SELECT computerdefaultprinter.printerid
              FROM computerdefaultprinter
              WHERE computerdefaultprinter.computerid = computermapping.computerid) = computermapping.printerid,
           'true',
           'false') AS isDefaultPrinter
FROM computermapping
LEFT JOIN computers ON computermapping.ComputerID = computers.ComputerID
LEFT JOIN printers ON computermapping.PrinterID = printers.PrinterID
LEFT JOIN computerdefaultprinter ON computers.ComputerID = computerdefaultprinter.ComputerID
WHERE computers.ComputerName = "Client02"
```

Comment: Thank you. I have problems on production-database with your sql-statement and I am currently trying to figure out why. I get the error "1242 -
 Subquery returns more than 1 row". Do you have an idea? You were talking about a better way? Maybe without having 2 queries?

Comment: It is happening because the computer mapping is finding more than 1 default printer for a specific client, let me fix the query sec

Comment: check the updated answer and let me know if it persists, the error was because a subselect can't return more than 1 result on its finding

Comment: Are you sure the wanted result 2 is correct? -> No, I am sorry. you are right. I did edit the request :-(

Comment: Thank you for the update. The query is working! I will test this further on production-db.